# How to send MultipartFile and Json in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot-maven-plugin

> Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;
    
    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ADD_PRODUCT')")
    @PostMapping(value = "/add", consumes = {
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    })
    public HttpEntity<?> addProduct(@CurrentUser User user,
                                    @RequestPart("files") MultipartFile multipartFile,
                                    @Valid @RequestPart("info") ProductDto productDto) {
        ApiResponse apiResponse = productService.addProduct(user, productDto, multipartFile);
        return ResponseEntity.status(apiResponse.isSuccess() ? 201 : 409).body(apiResponse);
    }

}
```

It should receive a `MultipartFile` and `Json object` and my `ProductDto` class is:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductDto {

    @NotNull(message = "Name can't be empty")
    @NotBlank(message = "Name can't be blank")
    private String name;
    
    @Length(max = 1000)
    private String description;
    
    
    @NotNull(message = "Price can't be empty")
    private double price;//Evaluated in the $
    
    @NotNull(message = "You should choose one of the categories")
    private UUID categoryId;

}
```

I'm finding difficulties when I try to send request:
[image]

But it always giving me `403 Forbidden` and I don't know the reason.

This request is not coming to `addProduct()` method at all and I have permission `"ADD_PRODUCT"`.

`@CurrentUser` annotation class is:

```
@Documented
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER) 
@AuthenticationPrincipal
public @interface CurrentUser { }
```

Not any error or exception is thrown as well.

I have tried `@RequestParam` and `@RequestPart` both annotations.

I want to learn how to deal with situations like this when sending `MultipartFile` and `Json` object simultaneously.

How can I do that in `Spring boot`?

Comment: A 403 means the role ADD_PRODUCT has not been added to the user’s security context. Please add the class that adds this role - named WebSecurityConfig or similar. Also what auth params are set up in postman

Comment: It has Role ADD_PRODUCT I double checked it.  Bearer Token

Comment: Please add the class that adds this role - named WebSecurityConfig or similar, ie how do the roles in the Bearer Token get into the security context?

Comment: Yeah you have a point there 
Now I try  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADD_PRODUCT')")

Comment: Did this fix the 403? If it did I would like to turn my comment into the accepted answer. Can you take the @PreAuthorize out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 in postman I usually get it when I use `http` instead of `https` in the URL. I think you can try editing the postman URL or if that doesn't work try to tell the spring boot app to use simple http.

Comment: I checked https as well but it didn't help